# Using DataAdapters and Relationships in VB.NET (Compact Framework)

Tags: database, vb.net, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

I have been looking for a solution for this problem for hours but nothing yet so here I am.

I have a dataset with 4 datatables:

```
    DS
    +Parent
    ++Child1
    ++Child2
    ++Child3
```

I defined relationships on the dataset which link the parent to the children using the pk's.

The problem is when I am filling (using the dataadapter.fill method) the child tables, the database returns ALL records and not just the ones related to the parent, so my datatables are larger than they need to be and are taking a while to load and since this code for a mobile device this is a premium.

I cant just use a WHERE filter on the children like I do on the parent as this depends on the parent data.

Is there some way to only return the records which are related to the parent when filling the children tables ?

I must be over looking something here as I thought this would be simple stuff ?!?

Thanks guys.

EDIT: The only ID known at the point of building the SELECT commands is the single common identifier for the parent table. This is no good to filter the child tables as this data is not present in them only the parent PK is, which is not known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only know the parent id, and that isn't enough to determine what records are needed in your child table, perhaps you could try a nested select that encapsulates your business logic:

```
SELECT * 
FROM child1 c
WHERE c.myforeignkey in 
    (
    select p.myforeignkey
    from parent p
    where p.parentid = ...
    )
```

On perhaps a LEFT JOIN?

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM child1 c
LEFT JOIN parent p on c.commonid = p.commonid
WHERE p.parentid = ...
```

Comment: I don't think SQLCE supports nested SELECT's

Comment: Ok, can probably get a similar result with a LEFT JOIN? I've edited my solution...

Comment: I have tried joins but the problem is all the data is returned at once and I need the data from the different tables in their own datatable so I can use code like: For Each ParentRow As DataRow In ds.Tables("Parent").Rows then use For Each ChildRow As DataRow In ParentRow.GetChildRows("Parent_Child") to access the related data.

Comment: with a join, everything is mashed in one table

Comment: With a join, everything you SELECT is mashed into one table. I was assuming this query was only for the Child1 data. There would be a separate query for Parent, Child 2 and Child 3

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps. I am basically using the data to display a sort of tree. So parent and all children data need to be in separate tables and with a join the parent will be with at least one child ?

Comment: I was using joins before but was returning rows as well. I never really thought of using the join for just the sake of the "relationship", but hey it works. I was hoping the DA adapter took care of all that once you added the relationships to the DS.

Answer (score 0):

You have said you are linking to the child table using parent PK = child fk therefore you will have a parentid column in the child tables.
So just as the query to fill the parent table is of the form SELECT * FROM parent WHERE parentid = @parentid, the query to populate the child tables would be of the form SELECT * FROM child1 WHERE parentid = @parentid

Comment: How do I do this because the ID of the parent row is not known when filling the child table. Say I have 10 parent rows they will all have the same common identifier buy not PK (obviously). The child table links to the parent row using the parent PK this field is defined in the child as a FK. How would I select the child rows based on the parent id when this is not known.

Comment: Is it possible to reference the parent table in the child select commands ?

Comment: yes it is. You can still use a join query - just don't return any fields from parent table. So you could do : SELECT child1.* FROM parent INNER JOIN child1 ON parent.parentid = child1.parentid WHERE parent.whatever = @whatever

Comment: In fact this is much the same as Derek was getting at in his JOIN example too.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing. I'll have to select Derek's response as the answer as he was in first with the join idea.